# Role based Authorization without Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

I love the way asp.net identity lets you neatly manage role based authorizations by just adding an annotation at the top of your controller method. But what if you are not using entity framework? What if you are using ADO.NET with ASP.NET Core API? How do you manage Role Based Authorization?

```
[Authorize(Roles = Role.Admin)]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
   var users =  _userService.GetAll();
   return Ok(users);
}
```

Perhaps we could mimic this by creating ActionFilter and checking what is the value of global variable that holds user's role? What are my options?

Comment: Authorization doesn't require a database. It looks at the roles (claims) in the current ClaimsPrincipal.

Comment: Please refer to this:[Role Based Authorization Tutorial with Example API](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/01/08/aspnet-core-22-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api)

Answer (score 0):

This is a great case for policy-based authorization. You'll use a custom `IAuthorizationHandler` and `IAuthorizationRequirement`. See the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.0

I've done this in a project recently. You create named policies, in your case something like "Admin". Your `AuthorizationHandler` will access the current user identity and can look up their current roles by injecting your services into the handler. Then you decorate your controller / actions with `[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]`.

In my project, my `AuthorizationHandler` and `AuthorizationRequirement` look like this:

```c#
public class CreateClientHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CreateClientRequirement, CreateClientRequest>, IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        private readonly IStudioService _studioService;

        public CreateClientHandler(
            IStudioService studioService
        )
        {
            _studioService = studioService;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
            AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
            CreateClientRequirement requirement,
            CreateClientRequest resource
        )
        {
            var userIdClaim = context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
            if (userIdClaim == null)
            {
                context.Fail();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            if (resource != null)
            {
                var userId = int.Parse(userIdClaim.Value);
                if (!UserIsAdmin(userId))
                {
                    context.Fail();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }

            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public class CreateClientRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement {}
```

In my `ConfigureServices`, in `Startup.cs`:

```c#
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CreateClient", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new CreateClientRequirement()));
    });
```

Once everything is configured, I can decorate controller actions with `[Authorize(Policy = "CreateClient")]`.